# Unable to retrieve physical size of available storage for cluster

Tags: powershell, wmi, cluster-computing, hyper-v

I am half way down with my work and now stuck.

I am trying to fetch information about available storage devices for a cluster.
I am able to fetch the list of available storage devices but unable to retrieve the physical disk, available free space, etc of these available storage.

I want like this. Is there any command to fetch physical disk name from Cluster Disk Name or directly can I get the disk details. 
For Shared Disk I am able to retrieve the details ([Get-ClusterSharedVolume](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460981.aspx)) but not for a non-shared disk.
I want powershell or WMI script for doing so.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get this information from WMI, but it takes a couple steps:

```
$resources = Get-WmiObject -namespace root\MSCluster MSCluster_Resource -filter "Type='Physical Disk'"
$resources | foreach {
    $res = $_
    $disks = $res.GetRelated("MSCluster_Disk")
    $disks | foreach {
        $_.GetRelated("MSCluster_DiskPartition") |
            select @{N="Name"; E={$res.Name}}, @{N="Status"; E={$res.State}}, Path, VolumeLabel, TotalSize, FreeSpace 
    }
} | ft
```

That will give you output like the following:

```
Name                  Status Path  VolumeLabel  TotalSize  FreeSpace
----                  ------ ----  -----------  ---------  ---------
Cluster Disk 2             2 K:    New Volume        5220       5163
SQL - FAS3070 SiteB        2 S:    MC_SQL            5597       5455
SM Test                    2 M:    SM Test           1024        992
DTC - FAS3070B             2 F:    MC_WITNESS        5346       5289
Cluster Disk Witness       2 E:    New Volume        5322       5267
Cluster Disk 1             2 G:    MC_DTC            5088       5035
Cluster Disk 3             2 T:    SQL               5119       4999
```

If you don't care about the resource name/status you can skip those steps and jump straight to the partition (and it'll run much quicker):

```
gwmi -namespace root\MSCluster MSCluster_DiskPartition | ft Path, VolumeLabel, TotalSize, FreeSpace
```

Edit: Note that the size is in MB and a Status of "2" means that the disk is online.

Comment: result looks pretty good. Currently i dont have access to cluster server. So i will give this script a try tomorrow.

Comment: Eric: Can you please help me on how can I filter the Volumelabel? I am getting volume lables are "App Cluster 1, App Cluster 2, Witness Disk, DB Cluster". I would like to list volumes with name like "App cluster ?" only.

Comment: I think you can just add `% { $_.VolumeLabel -match "^App cluster.*" }` to the end of the select or gwmi lines.

Answer (score 1):

you can use wmi like this:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_LogicalDisk -filter "DriveType=3" | Select DeviceID, FreeSpace
```

throw in a computername parameter if you wish to do it remotely

HTH,
Matt

PS. for a more readable report you can try this:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_LogicalDisk -filter "DriveType=3" | 
  Select DeviceID, @{Name = "Free Space (%)" ; Expression= {[int] ($_.FreeSpace / $_.Size* 100)}},@{Name = "Free Space (GB)"; Expression = {[int]($_.Freespace / 1GB)}}, @{Name = "Size (GB)"; Expression = {[int]($_.Freespace / 1GB)}}
```

Comment: i am not able to retrieve Drive Type. The only thing available is Name (like in image it is Cluster Disk 1). I am able to get this name "Cluster Disk 1" but from that how can i get the other details?

Comment: no error. there is as such no command (rather i would say i didn't got such command) to get other details from the volume name. I want output something like this. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clustering/archive/2010/06/19/10027366.aspx

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you mean by not getting the command. did you run it (or copy and paste) in a powershell command prompt?

Comment: That's a cool script, but it only gets the local disks.  In a cluster you'd only get the disk information if all the disks are online on the current node.

Comment: @Eric I had wondered about that (I don't have access to MS Cluster to test this at the moment). If it's run against the cluster though the current node is not relevant, no?

Comment: Well, the Win32* classes aren't really cluster aware, and each disk will only be online on one node at a time.  So the logical disks only includes disks that are online on the node you run the command.  You could issue it to all of the nodes though...

Comment: Yes the script provided here gives generic information about drives but not for clusters