# Check Free Space on a Clustered Disk using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, perfmon

i have clustered file server in azure, need to determine how much free space is available in the cluster using powershell whether we can use perfmon to achieve it, any code to achieve this

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Comment: So you want to know how to get  disk free space of your VMs?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are looking to get the information about Cluster Shared Volumes in a failover cluster, exploring the [Get-ClusterSharedVolume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/failoverclusters/get-clustersharedvolume?view=win10-ps) command might give some insights. Additionally, please check if the following resources help:

- [Monitor Cluster Shared Volume available disk space](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Monitor-Cluster-Shared-21de7554): This script will monitor the available free space on the Cluster Shared Volumes and if they fall below a set threshold it will send a webhook alert or an email. You can call this in the task scheduler of a cluster node member.
- [Powershell command to retrieve Failover Cluster Disk Size/Free Space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779315/powershell-command-to-retrieve-failover-cluster-disk-size-free-space)

Hope this helps!