# How do I get disk space statistics for a clustered disk

Tags: c#-4.0, wmi

I have a working program that retrieves information of disk such as FreeSpace, TotalSpace etc from a remote server. I have a problem however that i cannot get the same statistics for all **Clustered Disks** configured on the server. The query only returns information for the Local Disk (Logical Disk).

I am able to get sizes for Local Disk(:C) as below :

```
    public List<Disk> GetEnvironmentStatistics()
    {
        var serverIP = Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ServerIP"]); 

        List<Disk> diskinfo = new List<Disk>();

        //Add System.Management to access these utilities
        ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions
        {

            Username = Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"]),
            Password = Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Password"]),
            Authority = Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Authority"]),
        };

        //root - root of the tree, cimv2 - version           
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + serverIP + "\\root\\CIMV2", options);
        scope.Connect();

        SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
        ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();


            foreach (ManagementObject mo in queryCollection)
            {
                Disk disk = new Disk();
                disk.DiskName = mo["Name"].ToString();                  
                disk.DeviceId = mo["DeviceID"].ToString();
                disk.SystemName = mo["SystemName"].ToString();

                disk.FreeSpace = Convert.ToDecimal(mo["FreeSpace"]);
                var formattedFreeSpace = Helpers.DiskSpaceInGigabytes(disk.FreeSpace ?? 0);
                disk.FreeSpace = Decimal.Truncate(formattedFreeSpace);

                disk.TotalSpace = Convert.ToDecimal(mo["Size"]);
                var formattedTotalSpace = Helpers.DiskSpaceInGigabytes(disk.TotalSpace ?? 0);
                disk.TotalSpace = Decimal.Truncate(formattedTotalSpace);

                disk.UsedSpace = disk.TotalSpace - disk.FreeSpace;

                var HDPercentageUsed = 100 - (100 * disk.FreeSpace / disk.TotalSpace);
                disk.PercentageUsed = Convert.ToInt32(HDPercentageUsed);
                diskinfo.Add(disk);
            }



        return diskinfo;
    }
```

I have logged into the server and noted the other disks appear as Clustered Disk.

[image: DiskStructure]

I have researched a bit about the Clustered Disks  or Cluster Shared Volumes but the only guides i see include Powershell Scripting like here : [ClusteredSharedVolume Disk Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570650/unable-to-retrieve-physical-size-of-available-storage-for-cluster).

My question - how can i write a WMI query  that also retrieves information for Clustered Disks. Precisely  how i can adapt the query in the provided link for my needs :

```
    $resources = Get-WmiObject -namespace root\MSCluster MSCluster_Resource -filter "Type='Physical 
    Disk'"
    $resources | foreach {
       $res = $_
        $disks = $res.GetRelated("MSCluster_Disk")
$disks | foreach {
    $_.GetRelated("MSCluster_DiskPartition") |
        select @{N="Name"; E={$res.Name}}, @{N="Status"; E={$res.State}}, Path, VolumeLabel, TotalSize, FreeSpace 
}
    } | ft
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution requires invoking Powershell script in C# :

**1. Add System.Management.Automation Reference**

This dll enable access to Powershell utilities. The packages available on Nuget seem ahead and are not being recognized so i had to manually add the Reference by References >> Add Reference >> Browse >> C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management.Automation\1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35

Using Powershell i can get disk information for all Clustered Disks by the command :

```
get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Computername (ComputerName or IPAddress here)
```

**2. Invoke this command in code**
I added an extension method that checks for whether the remote host has Clustered Disks (if any) . If it indeed has , then use the Powershell script , if not then use normal WMI query :

```
public List<Disk> GetEnvironmentStatistics()
    {

        List<Disk> diskinfo = new List<Disk>();

        var serverIP = Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ServerIP"]);
        var clusterDisksStatus = CheckForClusteredDisks(serverIP);

        if (Helpers.HasClusteredDisks(clusterDisksStatus))
        {
            string getClusterSharedVolumesStatistics = "get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Computername " + serverIP + "";
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();              
            ps.AddScript(getClusterSharedVolumesStatistics);
            var results = ps.Invoke();

            foreach (var psobject in results)
            {

                if (psobject != null)
                {
                    Disk clusteredDisk = new Disk();
                    clusteredDisk.DiskName = Convert.ToString(psobject.Members["DeviceID"].Value);

                    clusteredDisk.FreeSpace = Convert.ToDecimal(psobject.Members["FreeSpace"].Value);
                    var formattedFreeSpace = Helpers.DiskSpaceInGigabytes(clusteredDisk.FreeSpace ?? 0);
                    clusteredDisk.FreeSpace = Decimal.Truncate(formattedFreeSpace);


                    clusteredDisk.TotalSpace = Convert.ToDecimal(psobject.Members["Size"].Value);
                    var formattedTotalSpace = Helpers.DiskSpaceInGigabytes(clusteredDisk.TotalSpace ?? 0);
                    clusteredDisk.TotalSpace = Decimal.Truncate(formattedTotalSpace);

                    clusteredDisk.UsedSpace = clusteredDisk.TotalSpace - clusteredDisk.FreeSpace;
                    clusteredDisk.VolumeName = Convert.ToString(psobject.Members["VolumeName"].Value);

                    diskinfo.Add(clusteredDisk);
                }



            }
        }

        else
        {

            //Add System.Management to access these utilities
            ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions
            {

                Username = Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"]),
                Password = Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Password"]),
                Authority = Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Authority"]),
            };

            //root - root of the tree, cimv2 - version           
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + serverIP + "\\root\\CIMV2", options);
            scope.Connect();

            SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk");
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
            ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();

            try
            {

                foreach (ManagementObject mo in queryCollection)
                {


                    Disk disk = new Disk();
                    disk.DiskName = mo["Name"].ToString();
                    disk.DeviceId = mo["DeviceID"].ToString();
                    disk.SystemName = mo["SystemName"].ToString();

                    disk.FreeSpace = Convert.ToDecimal(mo["FreeSpace"]);
                    var formattedFreeSpace = Helpers.DiskSpaceInGigabytes(disk.FreeSpace ?? 0);
                    disk.FreeSpace = Decimal.Truncate(formattedFreeSpace);


                    disk.TotalSpace = Convert.ToDecimal(mo["Size"]);
                    var formattedTotalSpace = Helpers.DiskSpaceInGigabytes(disk.TotalSpace ?? 0);
                    disk.TotalSpace = Decimal.Truncate(formattedTotalSpace);

                    disk.UsedSpace = disk.TotalSpace - disk.FreeSpace;

                    var HDPercentageUsed = 100 - (100 * disk.FreeSpace / disk.TotalSpace);
                    disk.PercentageUsed = Convert.ToInt32(HDPercentageUsed);
                    diskinfo.Add(disk);
                }
            }

            catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
            {

                ExceptionLogger.SendErrorToText(ex);
            }

        }
        return diskinfo;
    }
```

And the Helper method to check :

```
 public static bool HasClusteredDisks(int status)
    {
        int hasClusteredDisks = 1;
        if (status == hasClusteredDisks)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```